# Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) sonarqube “no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries”

Tags: docker, terminal, apple-m1

Here is my YAML file.

file name - docker-compose.mysonar.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    my-sonar:
        image: sonarqube:7.1
        ports:
            - 9001:9000
```

when I run
**docker-compose -f docker-compose.mysonar.yml up**
it throws the error - “no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries”

How do I fix this?

Comment: Default sonarqube is not supported for arm64, and not found in docker hub. How about try using this: amd64/sonarqube

Answer (score 32):

Apple M1 chips are ARM based architecture. When we run docker with `--platform linux/x86_64` option It's run on qemu emulation which won't give us the best performance. To get more information look at [docker apple-silicon docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/).

To get native performance of M1 chip you can do as below.

1. Build your own sonarqube image from Sonarqube [Dockerfile](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/9/community/Dockerfile) on Applie slicon.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube
cd docker-sonarqube/9/community

#build
docker build -t sonarqube-arm .

#run
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 sonarqube-arm
```

**OR**

2. You can use ARM based sonarqube docker image which I built recently on AWS ARM based server.

```sh
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 koolwithk/sonarqube-arm:9.2.4-community
```

Comment: thanks by the way for iniatively build the M1 image

Comment: I just want to mention I face an issue with run sonarqube-arm image, but I fix it by running the previous command as sudo:

```sudo docker run -d -p 9000:9000 sonarqube-arm```

Comment: it needs the build path also
so try 
`docker build ./ -t sonarqube-arm`

Comment: build path is already passed at the end as dot

Answer (score 30):

--platform linux/x86_64

Use this flag above for the commands where things are not working.

For eg.

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 sonarqube
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No, you can not run with --platform linux/x86_64. it's based on arm64 architecture

Comment: I am already doing it so...^

Comment: Just found out It's running on amd64 qemu emulation which won't give you best efforts. You will lose some performance and may drain your battery. You can also look into known issue here - https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: You can build your own docker image on M1 chip OR use already created arm64 docker image. I have added answer how you can do both.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this platform in the docker-compose.yml file as shown below

```
platform: linux/amd64
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  my-sonar:
      image: sonarqube:7.1
      platform: linux/amd64
      ports:
        - 9001:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the images in that repo have a single manifest in the manifest list for `linux/amd64`. You can try pulling the sha for that directly to see if it runs with virtualization. That tag for 7.1 is currently:

```
sonarqube@sha256:e36dcf59f4da62694a6e8265e6c56ca18596f59880f4cb6dd2c9efc6e0022405
```

Otherwise you could try to build the image for your platform, however the upstream image seems to indicate this is [not supported](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/103) and that they [won't fix it for the M1's either](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/460).

Comment: Thanks for your response @bmitch 
I tried the same and it didn't work for me. Found this from the SonarSource Community - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/CPP-2882
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/apple-silicon-issue/38774

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image it's works

[mwizner/sonarqube](https://hub.docker.com/r/mwizner/sonarqube/)

Comment: Error response from daemon: manifest for mwizner/sonarqube:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: @Lars I think you must add the version you want. E.g : `mwizner/sonarqube:9.4.0-community`

Comment: @snoobdogg, Thx, it might help others with same issue (although I think I tried it..not sure!).  Finally went for koolwithk's answer below which worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) it's easy form to use docker with other plataforms

To install

```bash
brew install colima
```

To use before start docker container

```bash
colima start --arch x86_64 --memory 4

docker run ...
```

To after use stop

```bash
colima stop
```