# SonarQube apple silicon support for android

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Not able to run SonarQube along with SonarScanner on mac M1 for my android studio project. Does SonarQube support m1 apple silicon. Tried installing linux/amb64 images but does not work for me stuck on SoanrQube loading for localhost url

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2021, [Sonarqube does not support Apple Silicon](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/apple-silicon-support-sonarqube-and-sonarscanner/55094/7).

> At that point, SonarQube doesn’t support the Apple M1 system which is based on arm.

But [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709003/1324345) may get you going with an unofficial way to do it.